# Operator undefined for type(s) int, ArrayList

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I wrote the following code to sum the elements of an `ArrayList<Integer>`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SumAverage {
    private int sum=0;
    public void getInput(ArrayList li )
    {
        System.out.println("Given elements are "+li);
    }
    public int sumOfElements(ArrayList<Integer> lis)
    {
        sum=sum+lis;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

> The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) int, ArrayList

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your problem is here "sum=sum+lis;"  the compiler does not know how to add an int with an arrayList.

Comment: What do you think `sum = sum + lis` is supposed to do? `+` can only be used between two numbers (addition), or strings (concatenation). There is no "addition" operation for lists.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the `List` in order to access every `Integer` and add it to the sum:

```
public void sumOfElements(ArrayList<Integer> lis)
{
    for (Integer num : lis) {
        sum = sum + num;  //Access each element in the list one at a time and add it to the sum
    }
}
```

You also should be using a `void` as your return type instead of `int` because there is no reason to return the class variable of `sum`.  It is already accessible from the class itself, so that return is redundant.

Here is an example on how to use this method assuming a standard getter method:

```
SumAverage sa = new SumAverage();
sa.sumOfElements(yourList);
int sum = sa.get(sum);  //Local variable now contains your class variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `lis` is an `ArrayList` and this type doesn't support the `+`, you need access to a position of the ArrayList with `list.get(x)`

But might you want this

```
public int sumOfElements(ArrayList<Integer> lis) {
     int total = 0
     for(int i = 0; i < lis.size(); i++){
         total += lis.get(i);
     }
     return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is with this piece of code.

```
public int sumOfElements(ArrayList<Integer> lis)
{ 
    sum=sum+lis;
    return sum;
}
```

the compiler does not know how to add an int with an arrayList.

what you need to do, is to iterate through each item in your list, and tabulate the total.

```
public int sumOfElements(ArrayList<Integer> lis)
{
    sum=0; //reset the total
    for(int i: lis){ //loop through each element in lis
        sum+=i;
    }
    return sum;
 }
```

for completeness sake, if you are using streams then it'll be something like this:- 
(don't need to worry about this now, grasp the fundamentals of Java first)

```
public int sumOfElements(ArrayList<Integer> lis)
{ 
    //it takes each item in lis, and sum them up.
    sum = IntStream.of(lis).sum();
    return sum;
 }
```

also as JoshhuaS mentioned, your print text may not return what you expect

```
public void getInput(ArrayList li )
{
    System.out.println("Given elements are "+li);
}
```

you can split your print statement into something like the following

```
public void getInput(ArrayList li )
{
    System.out.print ("Given elements are " ); //note it's print instead of println
    System.out.println(li); //this will print for example [1,2,3,4]
}
```

Comment: `"Given elements are "+li` is also a problem for a similar reason - this won't do what the OP thinks it does (if it compiles at all).

Comment: @EJoshuaS, that will compile without issues. internally, the compiler just converts it to li.toString()

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sitting in front of a Java compiler now. That definitely won't do what the OP thinks it does, though - the error there is similar to the error that the OP actually asks about.

Comment: @EJoshuaS, if he changes it to System.out.println(li), then the compiler will print just fine - example "[1,2,3,4]".  Appending with a string, will instead print the className+hex value

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to. The OP was presumably expecting `[1, 2, 3, 4]` rather than the className+hex value, so string concatenation won't do what the OP thinks it will in this case. I assume that the reasoning behind both mistakes in the code was similar (the fact that the OP presumably thought that the `+` operator would be applied to the entire list automatically).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're expecting that the `+` operator will automatically be applied to every element in `lis` and `li`. This is not the case for either `sum=sum+lis;` or `"Given elements are "+li`. You need to iterate over the `ArrayList` somehow in order to accomplish what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Exactly. "Apply this operator to every element" is something that is easy to do in Lisp. Java isn't really set up to do this fluently.

Comment: @RobertColumbia numpy too.